# How to structure your javascript code and functions?

Tags: javascript, function, structure

Im getting a good hold of javascript, which is helping me manipulate and making my DOM dynamic. But im lacking knowledge of how to structure my function and code, so its more interactive within.
In this example code below, how would you configure the code, so for instance when i add a new user or delete one, the #userContainer will automatic be updated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if(localStorage.myUsers){
      // APPENDING USERS IN localStorage.myUsers TO #userContainer
  }

  $(document).on("click", "#addUser", function() {
      // ADD USER TO LocalStorage.myUsers
  });

  $(document).on("click", "#deleteUser", function() {
      // DELETE $(this) USER FROM localStorage.myUsers
  });

}); // END OF document.ready
```

Comment: Are your talking about software patterns? If so checkout this MVC Frameworks which will help you to split controllers, models and views in its parts: http://codebrief.com/2012/01/the-top-10-javascript-mvc-frameworks-reviewed/

Comment: You want `two way data-binding`, AngularJS(http://angularjs.org/) is a great `MVW (W-Whatever)` javascript framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following best available javascript structure

```
'use strict'
var js = (function(){

var TestUsers = function(){
    // APPENDING USERS IN localStorage.myUsers TO #userContainer
};

var AddUsers = function(){
 $(document).on("click", "#addUser", function() {
      // ADD USER TO LocalStorage.myUsers
  });
};

var DeleteUsers = function(){
    $(document).on("click", "#deleteUser", function() {
      // DELETE $(this) USER FROM localStorage.myUsers
  });
}

return {
    InIt : function(){
        TestUsers();
        AddUsers();
        DeleteUsers();
    }
}
})();

$(function)(){
    js.InIt();
}
```

For more details visit:
[Javascript Code Organization - The Object Literal](https://swclass.com/Article/15/JAVASCRIPT-Code-Organization-The-Object-Literal)

Answer (score -2):

As long as your function to generate your html is not too heavy, this would be one way of doing it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if(localStorage.myUsers){
      PopulateUserContainer();
  }

  $(document).on("click", "#addUser", function() {
      // ADD USER TO LocalStorage.myUsers
      PopulateUserContainer();
  });

  $(document).on("click", "#deleteUser", function() {
      // DELETE $(this) USER FROM localStorage.myUsers
      PopulateUserContainer();
  });

}); // END OF document.ready

function PopulateUserContainer()
{
   //Clear html.
   // APPENDING USERS IN localStorage.myUsers TO #userContainer
}
```

Comment: The way you're doing it is just nice formatting, and you're suggesting the kid to create global function called PopulateUserContainer. The function name is also wrong, it should be lowercase unless you're really defining a reusable class/prototyped function.